# Popular type["text"] pela select

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou tentando popular um type["text"] através de jquery e não esta dando certo!

Formulário:

```
  <div>
        <label>Plano:</label>
        <select name="plano" id="plano" required>
             <?php echo $stringPlanos; ?>
        </select> <br /><br />
  </div>

  <div style="float:left">    
   <label class="labelPequeno">Valor</label><input type="text" class="real" style="width:100px; height:40px" required maxlength="23" id="valorCombinado"  name="valorCombinado" /> <br /><br />
  </div>
```

Código jquery

```
  <!-- INICIO ENTREGA VALOR DO PLANO -->
  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $('#plano').change(function(){
          if( $(this).val() ) {
              $.getJSON('planos.ajax.php?search=',{cod_plano: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(resultado){
                  var resultado = planosRetorno;
                  alert(resultado);
                  $('#valorCombinado').val(resultado).show();
              });
          } else {
              $('#valorCombinado').val('0.00');
          }
      });           
  });         
  </script>
  <!-- FIM ENTREGA VALOR DO PLANO -->
```

planos.ajax.php

```
<?php
 $cod_plano = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_plano'] );
 $planosBase = $PlanosDao->pesquisaPlanoEdicao($cod_plano);
 $planosRetorno = $planosBase->getValor();
 echo( json_encode($planosRetorno) );
?>
```

Mas, o console do navegador não mostra$ erros e o campo não é populado!

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Se o que queres popular é um `input` tens de usal `.val(resultado)` e não `.html(resultado)`. Será esse o problema?

Comment: $('#valorCombinado').val(resultado).show();??? Não funcionou. Mas acho que não. Pois nem o alert funciona!

Comment: Testa este código: http://jsfiddle.net/e3jdemdb/

Comment: Não vás mudando a pergunta por favor... deixa estar como estáva, mesmo que estivesse errado. Pode ser útil para outros.

Comment: Sérgio.  Não funcionou. Nem o alert funcionou!
Mas vale lembrar que estou usando o plugin autocomplete do jquery.Quer que eu adicione a chamada dele na pergunta?

Comment: Usa `echo json_encode($planosRetorno);` sem parentesis aqui: `echo()`.

Comment: Quando usas esse código que coloquei no jsFiddle o que te dá nos headers do ajax?

Comment: nem assim Sérgio. headers do Ajax? Como faço para ver isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29559/discussion-between-sergio-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: O que ocorre é que esses valores da select são alterados não na select, mas em uma UL com lis criadas dinamicamente. Nesse caso, terei que descobrir como pegar o valor da li selecionado! Será que tem geito?

Answer (score 1):

Opa amigo, você esta capturando a variável errado neste trecho de código:

```
          ...
          $.getJSON('planos.ajax.php?search=',{cod_plano: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(resultado){
              var resultado = planosRetorno;
              alert(resultado);
              $('#valorCombinado').val(resultado).show();
          });
          ...
```

A variável **resultado** esta capturando um valor errado: planosRetorno não existe, o retorno na verdade já é **resultado**

Caso esteja com problemas para verificar o erro da sua requisição faça um teste utilizando o método ajax do jquery:

```
$.ajax( "example.php")
    .done(function() {
        alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
    });
```

(http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Ok. Mas echo( json_encode($planosRetorno) ); não cria uma variável js de igual nome? Ou não é assim que interpreta?

Comment: na verdade a ideia é a seguinte:
`$.getJSON([url][parametro via get para a url][options], function([retorno da url]){ [função]});`